# What is wrong with this RDF.rb Query?

Tags: ruby, rdf, semantic-web

I'm learning rdf via the RDF.rb ruby library. I am able to load the following turtle file into a graph:

```
# filename: ex002.ttl

@prefix ab: <http://learningsparql.com/ns/addressbook#> .

ab:richard ab:homeTel "(229) 276-5135" . 
ab:richard ab:email   "richard49@hotmail.com" . 

ab:cindy ab:homeTel "(245) 646-5488" . 
ab:cindy ab:email   "cindym@gmail.com" . 

ab:craig ab:homeTel "(194) 966-1505" . 
ab:craig ab:email   "craigellis@yahoo.com" . 
ab:craig ab:email   "c.ellis@usairwaysgroup.com" .
```

But when I try to extract all triples with a #homeTel, using a query, I get no results at all. I am not sure if I have a basic misunderstanding of how the the query *should* work, or if I have a misunderstanding of how RDF.rb works, because I'm new to it all!

Here is the ruby code:

```
require 'rdf'
require 'rdf/ntriples'
require 'rdf/raptor'

graph = RDF::Graph.load("../data/ex002.ttl")

query = RDF::Query.new do
    pattern [:person, RDF::URI("http://learningsparql.com/ns/addressbook/#homeTel"), :o]
end

response = query.execute(graph)

puts "response: #{response.to_s}" # gives me an empty result
```

I've tried various alternative ways of representing the predicate, including a plain string with full uri, and "ab:homeTel, and an RDF::Vocabulary. If I just put ':p' in place of the predicate above it does return results so I know the graph is loaded ok.

I hope someone can help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prefix in the data is

```
@prefix ab: <http://learningsparql.com/ns/addressbook#> .
```

that means that `ab:homeTel` is the IRI

```
http://learningsparql.com/ns/addressbook#homeTel
```

However, in your query, you're using a different IRI:

```
RDF::URI("http://learningsparql.com/ns/addressbook/#homeTel")
#                                                 ^
#                                                 |
#                                       get rid of this slash
```

Comment: Doh! how many hours did I spend missing that? Many thanks Joshua!